# Post to MySpace link not working

Tags: javascript, html, myspace

I face a problem with post to MySpace link. Using PDF tutorial I created a simple page:

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function GetThis(T, C, U, L)
{
 var targetUrl = 'http://www.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=postto&' + 't=' + encodeURIComponent(T)
 + '&c=' + encodeURIComponent(C) + '&u=' + encodeURIComponent(U) + '&l=' + L;
 window.open(targetUrl);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="javascript:GetThis('An Important News Article Title',' ', 'http://www.newssite.com/article.php?id=123', 
'3')">
 <img src="http://cms.myspacecdn.com/cms/post_myspace_icon.gif" border="0" alt="Post to MySpace!" /> 
Share on MySpace get method!
</a>

<form id="myspacepostto" method="post" action="http://www.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=postto" 
target="_blank">
 <input type="hidden" name="t" value="An Important News Article Title" />
 <input type="hidden" name="c" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="u" value="http://www.newssite.com/article.php?id=123" />
 <input type="hidden" name="l" value="3" />
 <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myspacepostto').submit();return false;">
 <img src="http://cms.myspacecdn.com/cms/post_myspace_icon.gif" border="0" alt="Post to MySpace!" /> 
Share on MySpace post method!
 </a>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

There is an example with simple link and form. But when I use form link, request takes too long and no response from MySpace. If I use simple link to post content to MySpace then I get a 404 Error page. So how to post content to MySpace?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. My old links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL
http://mashable.com/2008/02/13/post-to-myspace/

This is from their website:

```
Actual Url: http://www.myspace.com/Modules/PostTo/Pages/?t=MySpace%20Post%20To%20Feature%20Example&c=%3Cp%3EHTML%20content%20to%20post%20goes%20here%20%3Ci%3E(e.g.%20text%2C%20images%2C%20objects%2C%20etc.)%3C%2Fi%3E%3C%2Fp%3E&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myspace.com&l=3
```

"Do not remove any of the parameters (T, C, U, L) – each is required. However, you do not need to put content in any of the fields; they could be left empty."